# External Keyboard only in qwerty

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, language-support

I am using a **BQ Aquarius E5 Ubuntu touch**. I can connect via USB or bluetooth a external keyboard. That works fine. But my normal keyboard = German and the external is always in qwerty (English).
I have already changed /etc/default/locales and keyboard to German.
Anybody have a idea, how can I turn my **external keyboard** into German (qwertz)
That is not only "y" and "z" changed ... I need Ö Ä Ü and so on.
Thanks
Christian from Munich